# How to remove old R base package? (R studio not working after update)

Tags: r, osx-mavericks, rstudio

I recently updated R from 2.15 to 3.1.  Since the update, I have not been able to run R-Studio.  R (v3.1) runs just fine independent of R-Studio.  I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing R-Studio, but it won't open.  Based on some sleuthing, the problem seems that R-Studio has a conflict with the older base package.  (My operating system is Mavericks.)

I found a terminal command to run to check the versions -- and this is what I got:

$ ls /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/
2.15    3.1 Current

Ok, I admit that I am not proficient with terminal commands, so I am hoping somebody could offer or point me to directions to remove the old base package.  Or, if you believe that the problem with R Studio is something else, let me know!

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: What happens if you run RStudio from the command line? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Opens and runs just fine on the command line -- no error!  Any thoughts on how I can get it working from the icon?

Comment: Exactly what error do you get when you run RStudio? Have you tried installing the latest version of Rstudio?

Comment: @hadley I actually didn't get any error message -- it would open but then remain blank with the spinner.  The problem started immediately after installing the latest R version.  I tried reinstalling Rstudio and that didn't work either.  But, Johathan's answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove the older version using `rm`:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/
$ rm -r 2.15
```

If you're more comfortable with Finder, you can use that too:

```
$ open /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions
```

(and just click and and delete the one you don't want)

Comment: Perfect.  That fixed the problem immediately -- very much appreciated.